Component not visible after using "setVisible(true)" on it and its parent
I've got a Java 8 app with a couple of JTextFields and a JButton to log into a database and a JTextArea inside a JScrollPane to display errors. Both the textarea and the scrollpane have to be hidden (setVisible(false)) if there's no error message to display.
public static ResourceBundle resourceBundle;
private static JTextArea textarea_error;
private JScrollPane scrollPane_error;
private JButton button_login;
private Connection connection = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle", Locale.English);
                Main frame = new Main(); 
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Error handling with the TextArea
            }
        }
    });
}

public Main() {
    textarea_error = new JTextArea();
    textarea_error.setEditable(false);
    textarea_error.setText("Error");
    scrollPane_error = new JScrollPane(textarea_error);
    scrollPane_error.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    button_login = new JButton(resourceBundle.getString("main.button.login"));
    button_login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            startLogin();
        }
    });
    //Aligning components,... here

    textarea_error.setVisible(false);
    scrollPane_error.setVisible(false); //this
}

private void startLogin() {
    //Read TextField input content here (user, pw, server-url)
    SwingWorker<String, String> sw = new SwingWorker<String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
            login(user,pw,server);
            return null;
        }
                
    };
    sw.execute();
}

private void login(String user, String pw, String server) {
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new SQLServerDriver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(server, user, pw);
        Statement s = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        scrollPane_error.setVisible(true); //this
        textarea_error.setText(resourceBundle.getString("main.error.userpw"));
        textarea_error.setCaretPosition(0);
        textarea_error.setVisible(true);
    }
}

The problem: catch is called when there's an error (e.g. wrong username or pw) but both the textarea and the scrollpane are still invisible. If I only change the textarea's visibility and always leave the scrollpane on visible (=remove both "this" lines - this also always displays the scrollpane's border), then this is working fine but as soon as I also set the scrollpane's visibility, neither it or its child come back.
I don't want to use setEnable because I want them to still use up space, even when they aren't needed.
I already tried to use invalidate, revalidate and repaint (even on the scrollpane) but that didn't help. The order in which I setVisible(true) both components also doesn't seem to matter.
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  The above is missing substantial code that prevents it from compiling.  And please keep it small enough to demo the problem (~ 70 lines or less).

Why are you setting the textarea_error to true inside the Exception handler?  And it looks like the scrollpane_error and textarea_error are initially set to false.

Why the downvote? Is there a website to test Swing/Java code, including a database to log into? I doubt I could keep it below 70 lines with the full layout. And yes, that's correct. The error box (textarea + scrollpane) should be hidden at the start and only made visible if there's actually an error message to display.

Most likely, the problem is that you’re modifying your components in the wrong thread—doInBackground is specifically for non-Swing activity.  Swing methods are only allowed to be called in the AWT event dispatch thread.  The body of your catch block should be wrapped in a call to EventQueue.invokeLater.

@VGR I know this should theoretically work that way but there are contradictory infos (although mostly old posts), so I decided to do both, just in case. I just tested it again and only changed the scrollpane's visibility (also cleaned the project after making the changes): Same problem, the error box doesn't appear. Does a CardLayout work inside a GroupLayout (horizontal/vertical/parallel)? All of this happens inside a regular JPanel inside a JFrame.

@VGR Re your edit: Thanks for the tip, I've had my fair share of problems with background threads. I wrapped everything inside the "catch" with a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { ... }}); (as shown here), cleaned the project again and tried again. No luck - again. Also tested it again with the scrollpane being permanently active, that's still working fine. Edit: Also tested EventQueue.invokeLater instead but no luck either.

A JPanel with a CardLayout is just a JPanel.  Its behavior will be the same as any other JPanel.  As long as the parent container respects its size (which nearly all layouts will), its use of a CardLayout will work.

@VGR Did I understand the documentation for CardLayout correctly as in that it's used to switch between two JPanels, so basically how different tabs switch between multiple windows' contents? That's not what I want/need. My login window is just that: A couple of textfields, a button and at the bottom there's an error box. The box is always there (but invisible) and if there's an error it's simply made visible to show the error message. There's no switching between different frames or panels.

Are you sure it’s not what you need?  If one of the children in a CardLayout is a blank JLabel, the CardLayout effectively can make the other children visible or invisible, while properly allocating space for them in advance.

@VGR Here's a screenshot: Orange is one JPanel, the JTextArea is cyan (when it's setVisible(true) at the start). The JScrollPane would be dark blue but it's covered by the textarea.

@WJS I added more code. Showing the full layout would make it way too long though (probably around 100 lines on its own).

Looks fine.  So why not try something like panelWithCardLayout.add(scrollPane_error, "content"); panelWithCardLayout.add(new JLabel(), "blank");?

@VGR I just tested something else: I set both the scrollpane and the textarea to false, as shown in my code, but then removed startLogin() inside the button's ActionListener and instead just switched on both components in there. This is definitely running on the main/GUI thread but when I click on the button, nothing happens. If I don't touch the scrollpane, then it instantly works again. I wonder if that's a bug with a 'JScrollPane'.

According to the code in your question, you are calling method login from a SwingWorker which means that method login does not run in the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) and you are setting the ScrollPane visible in that method.
Either call method login directly from method startLogin, i.e. do away with the SwingWorker completely, or, if you want to keep the SwingWorker, either add a done method to your SwingWorker or register a PropertyChangeListener with the SwingWorker (via method addPropertyChangeListener).
Here is a proof-of-concept (POC)
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class SwngWrkr implements Runnable {
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JScrollPane  scrollPane;
    private JTextArea  errorTextArea;
    private JPasswordField  passwordField;
    private JTextField  serverTextField;
    private JTextField  usernameTextField;

    public void run() {
        createAndDisplayGui();
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createSplitPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createErrorPanel() {
        errorTextArea = new JTextArea(15, 80);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(errorTextArea);
        scrollPane.setVisible(false);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JPanel createLoginPanel() {
        JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
        loginPanel.add(usernameLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        usernameTextField = new JTextField(16);
        loginPanel.add(usernameTextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        loginPanel.add(passwordLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(16);
        loginPanel.add(passwordField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        JLabel serverLabel = new JLabel("Server:");
        loginPanel.add(serverLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        serverTextField = new JTextField(16);
        loginPanel.add(serverTextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.addActionListener(this::doLogin);
        loginPanel.add(loginButton, gbc);
        return loginPanel;
    }

    private JSplitPane createSplitPane() {
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
                                              createLoginPanel(),
                                              createErrorPanel());
        return splitPane;
    }

    private void doLogin(ActionEvent event) {
        MyWorker myWorker = new MyWorker();
        myWorker.execute();
    }

    private class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        private Exception  error;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() {
            try {
                throw new RuntimeException("ARGH!");
            }
            catch (Exception x) {
                error = x;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            if (error != null) {
                errorTextArea.setText(error.toString());
                scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 600));
                scrollPane.setVisible(true);
                frame.pack();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new SwngWrkr());
    }
}

Here is a screen capture.

Initially, i.e. before pressing Login button.



After pressing Login button.


EDIT
Code below uses PropertyChangeListener rather than done method.
(Notes after the code.)
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class SwngWrkr implements Runnable {
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JScrollPane  scrollPane;
    private JTextArea  errorTextArea;
    private JPasswordField  passwordField;
    private JTextField  serverTextField;
    private JTextField  usernameTextField;

    public void run() {
        createAndDisplayGui();
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createSplitPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createErrorPanel() {
        errorTextArea = new JTextArea(15, 80);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(errorTextArea);
        scrollPane.setVisible(false);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JPanel createLoginPanel() {
        JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets.bottom = 10;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
        loginPanel.add(usernameLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        usernameTextField = new JTextField(16);
        loginPanel.add(usernameTextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        loginPanel.add(passwordLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(16);
        loginPanel.add(passwordField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        JLabel serverLabel = new JLabel("Server:");
        loginPanel.add(serverLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        serverTextField = new JTextField(16);
        loginPanel.add(serverTextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.setMnemonic('L');
        loginButton.addActionListener(this::doLogin);
        loginPanel.add(loginButton, gbc);
        return loginPanel;
    }

    private JSplitPane createSplitPane() {
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
                                              createLoginPanel(),
                                              createErrorPanel());
        return splitPane;
    }

    private void doLogin(ActionEvent event) {
        String username = usernameTextField.getText();
        char[] temp = passwordField.getPassword();
        String password = new String(temp);
        String server = serverTextField.getText();
        MyWorker myWorker = new MyWorker(username, password, server);
        myWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(this::handleLogin);
        myWorker.execute();
    }

    private void handleLogin(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
        String name = pce.getPropertyName();
        if ("state".equals(name)) {
            if (SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE == pce.getNewValue()) {
                Object source = pce.getSource();
                if (source instanceof SwingWorker task) {
                    try {
                        Object result = task.get();
                        if (result instanceof Connection databaseConnection) {
                            DatabaseMetaData dbmd = databaseConnection.getMetaData();
                            System.out.println(dbmd.getDatabaseProductName());
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception x) {
                        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                        x.printStackTrace(pw);
                        errorTextArea.setText(sw.toString());
                        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 600));
                        scrollPane.setVisible(true);
                        frame.pack();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new SwngWrkr());
    }
}

class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Connection, Void> {
    private String  username;
    private String  password;
    private String  server;

    public MyWorker(String username, String password, String server) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    protected Connection doInBackground() throws Exception {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(server, username, password);
    }
}


Making scrollPane visible is now done in method handleLogin, of class SwngWrkr and therefore class MyWorker can now be a separate class since it no longer needs to access any of the GUI components declared in class SwngWrkr.
Above code uses method references and also pattern matching for instanceof.
You no longer need to explicitly register the JDBC driver class, hence you can safely remove this line of your code:

DriverManager.registerDriver(new SQLServerDriver());


If the database connection fails, errorTextArea will display the entire stack trace.


'login' has to run within a background thread because it's establishing a connection to the database. Please check the comments underneath the question, VGR suggested calling the "catch" code inside 'EventQueue.invokeLater'. I tested both that and 'SwingUtilities.invokeLater' but the 'JScrollPanel' still never became visible, while it's still working fine (with or without 'invokeLater') if I only change the visibility of the 'JTextArea'.

@Neph 'login' has to run within a background thread because it's establishing a connection to the database No it doesn't. In any case, I also told you what to do if you want to keep the SwingWorker. Please read the links in my answer.

I don't understand what a PropertyChangeListener would do here. The docs say that it reacts to changes but that's basically what the "login" button is already doing when pressed: Its ActionListener calls a function that starts the SwingWorker, which then connects to the db. It shouldn't matter if I use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater, as suggested by VGR (advantage: handle the exception directly, without saving it "for later"), or handle the exception in 'done'. I already tried the former but it didn't change anything, while the textarea became visible (no matter what thread) without the SP.

@Neph added another POC demonstrating use of PropertyChangeListener.

Thanks, I'll properly check it out when I'm back next week.

Here's a simple example I created.

When the GUI comes up, the JTextArea and JScrollPane are set to not visible.  When you click on the Login JButton, the JTextArea and JScrollPane will become visible and display an error message.

Here's the complete runnable code.  All 102 lines of it.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LoginExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LoginExample());
    }

    private JFrame frame;

    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    private JTextArea errorArea;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Login Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createLoginPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createMessagePanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel createLoginPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("UserID:");
        panel.add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        JTextField useridField = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(useridField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Password:");
        panel.add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
        panel.add(passwordField, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton button = new JButton("Login");
        panel.add(button, gbc);

        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            errorArea.setText("Error message");
            errorArea.setVisible(true);
            scrollPane.setVisible(true);
            frame.pack();
        });

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createMessagePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        errorArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
        errorArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        errorArea.setLineWrap(true);
        errorArea.setEditable(false);
        errorArea.setVisible(false);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(errorArea);
        scrollPane.setVisible(false);

        panel.add(scrollPane);

        return panel;
    }

}

Edited to add: "How come the space the error box is occupying isn't visible when the error box isn't visible"
I made the JTextArea and the JScrollPane not visible.  If you make just the JTextArea not visible, the JScrollPane will be visible and take up space.
"Did this work multiple times for you?"
I demonstrated the process.  The process is designed to work one time.
Your code relies on a GUI builder.  You should hand code the GUI, as I did in my example.

Thanks for the example. How come the space the error box is occupying isn't visible when the error box isn't visible (is it because of 'frame.pack()'?)? Did this work multiple times for you? I tried to simply change the visibility on button click the way you do but if I set the scrollpane to invisible first, the error box still doesn't reappear. It only works if I don't touch the scrollpane's visibility.

@Neph: See the notes I added to the bottom of the answer.

Thanks for the edit, my mistake, I forgot that I set my window to a fixed height. I noticed that you don't use any version of validate in your code. That's exactly how I'm doing it (tested with main and background thread), but the scrollpane just never reappears, even when I call it on button click (which is definitely the main thread). Have you still got the project? If so, could you please try using a fixed height too and then remove frame.pack() in the listener (no need to add that code to your answer). Does your scrollpane then still appear after clicking the button?

@Neph: Instead of me modifying my code to no longer work, how about you modify your code to work properly.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Sorry about the delay. That's what I'm trying to do: I want to figure out what the problem with my current code is, so I can fix it. It's definitely weird that setting the ScrollPane invisible breaks this way, the docs don't mention anything. If you modify your code and it stops working, then it might have something to do with the fixed height (sucks) or pack. If it doesn't, then at least I'll know that it's a different problem altogether. Btw, I'm using a GroupLayout and the class extends JFrame.
